# Header is changed to upper case only when uploading to arXiv

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, arxiv

I wrote an essay using Overleaf and I am trying to upload it to arXiv. When I compile it on Overleaf or locally using `pdflatex main.tex` the section name in the header is lowercase. I get the following:

[image: locally compiled document]

When I upload to arXiv however it is in uppercase (this is in the processing stage where it said it succeeded). In both cases I have an author name on the right side of the header where the case behaves as I expect (no difference between them).

[image]

Here is the code of my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Author Name}
\lhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}

\section{Section name}

This is some text

\end{document}
```

On Overleaf I am using TexLive 2023 with the pdflatex compiler. When I compile it from the terminal I use TexLive 2022 with the pdflatex compiler. I have checked that arXiv uses TexLive 2023, and in the logs it confirms that it is using the pdflatex compiler.

My question is why does arXiv produce different results? How can I fix this?

Full log:

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2023 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5120620/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file main.aux.
[1{/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.

)</texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 25278 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: WARNING: Supplemental 'rerun' check detected need for extra pass.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5120620/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./main.aux
) (./main.out) (./main.out) [1{/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/
pdftex.map}] (./main.aux) )</texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 25386 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1695415187 >= 1695415185)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1695415187 >= 1695415185)
[verbose]: now stamping pdf file 'main.pdf' with stamp 'arXiv:submit/5120620 [math.NA] 22 Sep 2023'
[verbose]: stamped pdf file
[verbose]: PDFTEX paper, check "/opt_arxiv/arXivTeX/submissions/5120620/".

[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: AutoTeX made a pdf.
[verbose]: Moving .../5120620/main.pdf => .../5120620/tex_cache/5120620.pdf

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Full log after adding `\listfiles` after `pdfoutput = 1`:

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2023 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5120620/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file main.aux.
[1{/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

*File List*
article.cls 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
babel.sty 2023/04/18 3.88 The Babel package
english.ldf 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
babel-english.tex
fancyhdr.sty
hyperref.sty 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hypertext links for LaTeX
ltxcmds.sty 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
iftex.sty 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
keyval.sty 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
hycolor.sty 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
auxhook.sty 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
nameref.sty 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
etoolbox.sty 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
pd1enc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
intcalc.sty 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
puenc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
bitset.sty 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
hpdftex.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
***********


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck) or use package `bookmark'.

)</texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 25278 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: WARNING: Supplemental 'rerun' check detected need for extra pass.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5120620/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-english.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./main.aux
) (./main.out) (./main.out) [1{/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/
pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

*File List*
article.cls 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
babel.sty 2023/04/18 3.88 The Babel package
english.ldf 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
babel-english.tex
fancyhdr.sty
hyperref.sty 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hypertext links for LaTeX
ltxcmds.sty 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
iftex.sty 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
keyval.sty 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
hycolor.sty 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
auxhook.sty 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
nameref.sty 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
etoolbox.sty 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
pd1enc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
intcalc.sty 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
puenc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
bitset.sty 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
hpdftex.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend-ltx.sty 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
main.out
main.out
***********

)</texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 25386 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1695755824 >= 1695755823)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1695755824 >= 1695755823)
[verbose]: now stamping pdf file 'main.pdf' with stamp 'arXiv:submit/5120620 [math.NA] 26 Sep 2023'
[verbose]: stamped pdf file
[verbose]: PDFTEX paper, check "/opt_arxiv/arXivTeX/submissions/5120620/".

[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: AutoTeX made a pdf.
[verbose]: Moving .../5120620/main.pdf => .../5120620/tex_cache/5120620.pdf

[verbose]: All generated files successfully moved.
[verbose]: ** AutoTeX job completed. **
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the complete log from arXiv?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the log. Also I've just noticed that sometimes it says it is using hpdflatex, I need to research what that is.

Comment: the version from arxiv is a bit older than a current texlive and that is difficult to test. Simply redefine \sectionmark, then you no longer need to worry: `\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth {\thesection \hskip 1em\relax #1}{}}`

Comment: I tried redefining `\sectionmark` in the preamble, and it hasn't changed anything. When I use `\lhead{\sectionmark}` instead of `\lhead{\leftmark}` then it does not show anything in the left header, with or without the `\renewcommand` line. Using `\lhead{\thesection}` on its own works but it only shows the section number.

Comment: `\lhead{\sectionmark} is wrong. Try to move the redefinition after \begin{document}. arxiv probably adds some code before (your log e.g. shows that hyperref is loaded).

Comment: I have replaced `\lhead{\sectionmark}` with `\lhead{\leftmark}` again and placed the redefinition after `\begin{documents}`, but it still doesn't work. I am going to experiment more with the version of TexLive tomorrow.

Comment: probably unrelated but your `\typeout{get arXiv to do 4 passes: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun}` will never be executed

Comment: I suspect that there's a subtle package difference. I added `\listfiles` to your code on arXiv. You might want to update your log output above to indicate this info for the more guru level folks on this thread, after which you can try dropping in any package more recent. `fancyhdr` on arXiv is in the same head version on ctan (even though it won't show that in the log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a configuration issue in arXiv's tex tree, where it's loading version 3.2 instead of the current build in the tree (which is indeed 4.1). You can replicate this behavior locally by downloading that version and trying to compile it locally.

I've put in a bug report for this, but for now you can just add the `fancyhdr.sty` package from your local tex installation to have the desired functionality.

Comment: This solved my problem! I have successfully recreated it locally and also fixed it on arXiv. For those with the same issue I got the correct version of the `fancyhdr.sty` package from https://github.com/pietvo/fancyhdr/blob/66571991266d55f93588b20644259edf06fd2cb2/fancyhdr.sty, and you just upload that to arXiv as well to fix the issue.